# Push Notification in objective-c when the App is Force Quit in Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter, nsapplication

How to push notifications when the user force quits the app or when the app is force killed from activity monitor?

Comment: Did you tried using applicationWillTerminate in app delegate?

Comment: Yes, it was not getting called. I even tried NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification without using app delegate.